# Biopython not working on Window 7 64 (import bio function not working)

Tags: python, import, biopython

I am having trouble using biopython as my 'import bio' does not work.

I have Window 7 , 64-bit system with Python 2.7.1 with Piston, Django and NumPy site packages installed and they all work well with the import function.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post some code where you import it and then what error messages arises if you want us to help you.

Comment: I don't think it is helpful to cross post on both stackoverflow and biostar, http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/9947/biopython-not-working-on-window-7-64-import-bio-function-not-working

Answer (score 0):

From the biopython download page.

> Note we don't (yet) have official [64 bit Windows Installers](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) - however, Christoph Gohlke has kindly made Windows 64bit installers for NumPy and Biopython (and other tools) available for testing.

Did you install the 32bit package? If so, try uninstalling it and installing the 64bit one.

Comment: So when I started Python by typing Python in Command Prompt- its goes
Python 2.7.1  <r....
>>> import bio
Traceback <most recent call last>:
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module name bio
>>>


the funny thing is when I look at ...lib>site-packages>,
there is Bio and BioSQL (using window explorer)

any help would be much appreciated!

peterjc: opps, you found out, sorry for that... just thought it increase my chances lol

Comment: haha.. found out the issue:

I should have use "import Bio" instead of "import bio"..  silly me.

thanks all for the help !! :D